# Name for a polynomial equation with fractional exponents?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

I have to solve an equation in the form:

$$
\alpha\cdot\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau_1}) + \beta\cdot\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau_2}) = \Theta
$$

which has the form

$$
\alpha\cdot x + \beta\cdot x^\gamma  = \Theta
$$

where $\gamma = \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}$. In my case, I know $x \geq 0$ and $\gamma\geq 1$, but in general I am interested in knowing if such problem has a generic name, and better, a simple solution :-)

Comment: This is just a polynomial equation in $x$. I don't believe there is anything special. Nor is there a simple/general solution

Comment: it is polynomial if $\gamma$ is an integer, but in the general case where it is a real ?

Comment: I don't see why it still would not be considered a polynomial function, unless if $\gamma$ was negative.

Comment: That's also what I would assume, but most definition agree about "integer exponentiation" (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial )

Comment: Seems they have slightly different terminology - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posynomial. Still I wouldn't expect a general solution from such problems.

Further if $\gamma$ is rational you can transform to a variable where this function would be a polynomial.

Comment: thanks @Gregory ! could you transform your comment to an answer?